# Trying to map data from json file to netfix clone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netflix

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBb0t.png)
I am trying to map data from my json file

```
export const products = [
    {
        name: 'iPhone 11',
        image: '/assets/images (7).jpeg',
        time: '1 hour 14mins',
        age: '+16',
        year: '1999',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium hic rem eveniet error possimus, neque ex doloribus.',
        genre: 'Action',
        id: 0,
    },
    {
        name: 'iPhone 11',
        image: '/assets/images (13).jpeg',
        time: '1 hour 14mins',
        age: '+16',
        year: '1999',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium hic rem eveniet error possimus, neque ex doloribus.',
        genre: 'Action',
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'iPhone 11',
        image: '/assets/images (14).jpeg',
        time: '1 hour 14mins',
        age: '+16',
        year: '1999',
        desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium hic rem eveniet error possimus, neque ex doloribus.',
        genre: 'Action',
        id: 2,
    }
]
```

to my netflix clone, when i map it and hover it the image hovers but the next image takes the position of the hovered image, sorry if the code is too long, its so you can get my point
here is the code
List.js and Listitem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  ArrowBackIosOutlined,
  ArrowForwardIosOutlined,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ListItem from "../listItem/ListItem";
import "./list.scss";
import { products } from './listdata'

export default function List() {
  const [isMoved, setIsMoved] = useState(false);
  const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0);

  const listRef = useRef();

  const handleClick = (direction) => {
    setIsMoved(true);
    let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50;
    if (direction === "left" && slideNumber > 0) {
      setSlideNumber(slideNumber - 1);
      listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${230 + distance}px)`;
    }
    if (direction === "right" && slideNumber < 5.6) {
      setSlideNumber(slideNumber + 1);
      listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-230 + distance}px)`;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="list">
      <span className="listTitle">Continue to watch</span>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <ArrowBackIosOutlined
          className="sliderArrow left"
          onClick={() => handleClick("left")}
          style={{ display: !isMoved && "none" }}
        />
        <div className="container" ref={listRef}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>
              <ListItem product={product} />
          </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <ArrowForwardIosOutlined
          className="sliderArrow right"
          onClick={() => handleClick("right")}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "./listItem.scss";
import trail from '../../assets/The Imperfects _ Official Trailer _ Netflix.mp4'
import {
  PlayArrow,
  Add,
  ThumbUpAltOutlined,
  Check,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import { useState } from "react";
// import StyleSh
export default function ListItem({ product }) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const trailer = trail;
   const isTrue = product.id;
  return (
    <div
      className="listItem"
      style={{left: isHovered && product.id * 225 - 50 + product.id * 2.5}}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      <img
        src={product.image}
        alt=""
      />
      {isHovered && (
        <>
          <video height='180px' src={trail} autoPlay={true} loop />
          <div className="itemInfo">
            <div className="icons">
              <PlayArrow className="icon" style={{color: 'black'}} />
              <Check className="icon" />
              <Add className="icon" />
              <ThumbUpAltOutlined className="icon" />
            </div>
            <div className="itemInfoTop">
              <span>{product.time}</span>
              <span className="limit">{product.age}</span>
              <span>{product.year}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="desc">
            {product.desc}
            </div>
            <div className="genre">{product.genre}</div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

note am not using an API, I don't want to

Answer (score 0):

Updated ListItem component

```
import React from "react";
import "./listItem.scss";
import trail from "../../assets/The Imperfects _ Official Trailer _ Netflix.mp4";
import { PlayArrow, Add, ThumbUpAltOutlined, Check } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { useState } from "react";
// import StyleSh
export default function ListItem({ product }) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const trailer = trail;
  const isTrue = product.id;
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", height:"180px", width:"200px" }} onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}>
      <div
        className="listItem"
        style={{
          left: isHovered && product.id * 225 - 50 + product.id * 2.5,
          position: isHovered ? "absolute" : "relative",height:"100%", width:"100%"
        }}
      >
        <img src={product.image} style={{height:"100%",width:"100%",object-fit:"cover"}} alt="" />
        {isHovered && (
          <>
            <video height="180px" src={trail} autoPlay={true} loop />
            <div className="itemInfo">
              <div className="icons">
                <PlayArrow className="icon" style={{ color: "black" }} />
                <Check className="icon" />
                <Add className="icon" />
                <ThumbUpAltOutlined className="icon" />
              </div>
              <div className="itemInfoTop">
                <span>{product.time}</span>
                <span className="limit">{product.age}</span>
                <span>{product.year}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="desc">{product.desc}</div>
              <div className="genre">{product.genre}</div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it brings all the image to one div, and the image glitch loads

Comment: oh then I made changes in code please check above

Comment: wait that will not work does it? please check

Comment: if i hover, it moves the next two images to one block. it doesn't still work

Comment: try this-> add parent div and make relative position. See above code

Comment: yh, I did it and it and it glitches the hovering

Comment: you need to set fixed width on parent div and move mouseEnter and MmouseLeave attribute to parent div, maybe that should fix it

Comment: look at the codes above if you need me to send you more detailed codes I can check if the styling is the problem

Comment: check above code, made some changes

Comment: sorry, didn't work